# How many times does a Mature Animal Companion attack per encounter without orders?

Tags: feats, ranger, animal-companions, pathfinder-2e

The Mature Animal Companion feat for Rangers (CRB p173) is really ambigious:

> If you **have** the Hunt Prey action, your animal companion assaults the prey even without your orders. During an encounter, even if you don’t use the Command an Animal action, your animal companion can still use 1 action that round on your turn to Stride toward or Strike your prey.
>   (emphasis mine)

It makes a lot more sense with **use** instead of **have**, otherwise I might not even have a Prey for it to Strike.
But in that case, next round, when the Prey is still alive, will my Animal Companion just stand around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You can use it every round when you do not use Command Animal

It isn't a typo, just bad editing after a copy-paste. It is quite clear once you understand the original, the Druid feat of the same name (CRB p135):

> Your animal companion is better trained than most. During an encounter, even if you don’t use the Command an Animal action, your animal companion can still use 1 action on your turn **that round** to Stride or Strike.
> (Emphasis mine)

Clearly *that round* refers to rounds when you do not use Command Animal. When you compare this to the Ranger feat you can see how Hunt Prey was added.
So Hunt Prey is not necessary to trigger this action, only to provide a valid target.

Comment: Even this way it is strictly worse than the Druid version, while of higher level. Does not bode well for balance between classes.

Comment: Context may add some balance; for example a ranger will in general gain significantly greater benefit from flanking than a druid will (due to taking more strikes). I'm not saying it does balance the two, but that comparing them directly outside context wont give the full picture.